# Which is the proper way to expose a service using the nginx RBAC ingress controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rbac, kubeadm

I am using kubeadm tool so to create a kubernetes v1.7 cluster.

It is quite simple to expose the service "echoheaders" on my host `kubenode1.kube.com` using external-ip

Create a deployment running:

```
kubectl run echoheaders --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.5
```

Expose a service from the deployment:

```
kubectl expose deployment echoheaders --port=80 --target-port=8080 --external-ip='192.168.10.96'
```

Access it from you web-browser:

```
http://kubenode1.kube.com
```

Now, I would like to expose the same service `echoheaders` using the Role Based Ingress Controller from this guide:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/rbac/nginx

From the above guide I am running the commands without a problem..

After that, create the deployment and service "echoheader" with type:NodePort but without using the external-ip option

```
kubectl run echoheaders --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.5

kubectl expose deployment echoheaders --port=80 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort
```

We are able to access the service with `curl 192.168.10.96:31782`

Creating also the echoheaders ingress resource for this service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echoheaders-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubenode1.kube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: echoheaders
              servicePort: 80
```

But I am not able to access the service:

```
curl http(s)://kubenode1.kube.com -H "Host: kubenode1.kube.com"
```

returns

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to kubenode1.kube.com:80; Connection Refused
```

Everything seems to be ok when I am checking the command:
kubectl describe ing echoheaders

Last I have tried the kubernetes-dashboard service from here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

This is compatible of Kubernetes 1.6 RBAC enabled.. but also I wasn't able to access it from outside.
Still getting the same error:

curl: (7) Failed connect to kubenode1.kube.com:80; Connection Refused

Do I have to provide more details? 
Am I missing something so to be able to expose a service using the Role based nginx-ingress controller?

I need to access my services from http(s)://kubenode1.kube.com and not to be publicly accessible on Nodeport port (http(s)://kubenode1.kube.com:31782)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the nginx controller on nodeport 80 if you want to access it on that port. It looks like the example you linked to exposes it on port 30080: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/examples/rbac/nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-service.yml

For using port 80 you first have to allow such low port numbers for nodeport services. You can do that with the `--service-node-port-range` parameter of the apiserver, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was able to expose services using this way! Is this a recommended way? If yes, the documentation isn't clear I think..

Comment: we are using k8s on AWS, behind an AWS loadbalancer. So the AWS  loadbalancer listens on ports 80 / 443, and forwards traffic to a high node port, no need for us to make the Ingress Controller listen on port 80 as well. But if you don't have another lb in front of nginx, and you want to use port 80, this is the only way to my knowledge.